# Node.js Which part i did wrong? server.js is running, but i cant see the html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

This is what i have so far, i am running this in putty,

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
const POST =8080
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var url = request.url;
    switch(url) {
    case '/':
        console.log('1');
        getStaticFileContent(response,'templates/Assignment1.html','text/html');
        break;
    case'/new':
        console.log('2');
        getStaticFileContent(response,'templates/new.html','text/html');
        break;
    default:
        response.writeHead(404,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
        response.end('404 - Page not Found.');
     }
}).listen(POST)

console.log('Server is running');

function getStaticFileContent(response, filepath, contentType) {
    fs.readFile(filepath, function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            response.writeHead(500,{'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            response.end('500 - Internal Server Error.');
        }
        if (data) {
            response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.end(data);
        }
    });
}
```

when i add those console.log('1') in the cases, these error pops out.

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1039:14)
at listen (net.js:1061:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1135:5)
at Object.<anonymous> (/net/files.cis.ksu.edu/exports/home/y/yuex/CIS526/server.js:21:4)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

can someone tell me where i did it wrong?

Comment: First of all the error `listen EADDRINUSE` means you're trying to run multiple servers on the same port simultaneously.

Comment: Your code is completely okay but Your port already in use

Comment: i tried other numbers like 8888, 3000..still doesn't work..

Comment: @ThomasXie And you get still the same error?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the server is listening for the same port, which is already occupied by another application. Free up the port, or try to listen for another port. The rest of the code seems ok.

Run this linux command to check if the port you are listening is already occupied:

```
netstat -an | grep <port number>
```

or

```
netstat -aon | more
```

Comment: I just tried several different number..  either i am keep getting that error, or cant access the web page...